# The function is missing from MBCB package

Tags: r

I'm using `MBCB` package to perform background correction for microarray data. All worked well until I tried to output the values using `printMBCBOutput` function (this function listed in documentation for this purposes). I've got this error:

> Error: could not find function "printMBCBOutput"

I've checked if this function is in my installed `MBCB` package, and it is NOT:

```
lsf.str("package:MBCB")
bg.mcmc : function (iter = 500, burn = 200)  
bg.rma : function (pm, n.pts = 2^14)  
mbcb.correct : function (g, control, npBool = TRUE, rmaBool = FALSE, mleBool = FALSE, bayesBool = FALSE, 
    gmleBool = FALSE, iter = 500, burn = 200, isRawBead = FALSE)  
mbcb.gui : function ()  
mbcb.main : function (signal, control, npBool = TRUE, rmaBool = FALSE, mleBool = FALSE, bayesBool = FALSE, 
    gmleBool = FALSE, paramEstFile = "param-est", bgCorrectedFile = "bgCorrected", iter = 500, 
    burn = 200, normMethod = "none", isRawBead = FALSE)
```

Can anyone suggest why this function is missing from `MBCB` package and what can be done to fix this, please?

I'm using R-3.2.1 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `printMBCBOutput()` function is not showing up the `MBCB` package because it does not appear to be part of this package, at least not according to the recent PDF documentation available by typing `browseVignettes("MBCB")` in the R console.

My hypothesis is that you were using [this documentation](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MBCB/functions/printMBCBOutput) to go by, which *does* mention `printMBCBOutput()` but is only version `1.16.0`.  However, the package which I installed from [this source](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/MBCB.html) appears to be version `1.20.0`.  I believe the function in question has been removed from the package in the version we were all testing.

That being said, my guess is that you won't need this function to do what you need.  I suspect that the interface you listed in your OP will either have incorporated the functionality previously contained in `printMBCBOutput` *or* there are other R packages which can do this.

Comment: There is a `MBCB:::printMBCBOutput` in `MBCB` package version 1.23.0.

Comment: Strange...welcome to the wild world of open source, where you never really know which version you are using or which documentation should be used.

Comment: @Pascal Can you edit my answer by providing a link to where you downloaded the `1.23.0` version?  Or you can answer yourself if you like.

Comment: I think it is because I use the [**devel** version of Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/developers/how-to/useDevel/), i.e. version 3.2. The **release** version of Bioconductor is 3.1 and installs version `1.22.0` (typo in your post) of `MBCB`.

Comment: OK thanks for the good information.  The owners of this package should really have a central location, like the Maven Central Repository, where everyone can go to obtain versioned downloads.

Comment: If I may object, the package is located on Bioconductor, which more or less works like CRAN (or MRAN).